# How to finish creme brulee in TooManyChefs.Party

Tags: too-many-chefs

At the final stage Too Many Chefs, the Patissier has to move the blowtorch over the creme brulee.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to complete this.

[image: Creme Brulee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the fire over **\cb3/** and leave it there.

**Done** is a red herring.